# asynchronous callback in a Jquery tab

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, jquery-ui

at the moment im working alone at a big project for a company. One part is the CMS, and i want to use tabs for it.

Here i create the JQuery tabs

```
  $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs({cookie:{}, closable: true });

    });

    function addnewtab(name,link)
    {
         $tabs .tabs("add", link, name, tabcounter);
        $tabs.tabs("select", tabcounter);
        tabcounter++;

    }
```

Here i open a new tab, and load the file Products.aspx.

```
onclick="addnewtab('Products','Products.aspx')"
```

And here is the Products.aspx with the task to search for products and schow them in the gridview. I cuted the content of the Gridview for overview purposes.

Everything works fine, but the problem is that the hole cms site is refreshed, and only the Products.aspx with the right content is opened.

Is it possible that only the content of the tab is refreshed?

```
<form id="form1"  runat="server">
       <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1"   runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
         <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>

        <div >

             <table class="style1">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Filter: " />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                     <asp:Textbox ID="tb_keyword"  CssClass="dp_field" runat="server">
                            </asp:Textbox>
                        </td>

                        <td>
             <asp:Button ID="btn_get" runat="server"  OnClick="search" Text="Search" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </div>





     <asp:gridview id="gvProduct" runat="server" allowpaging="True">                         
        </asp:gridview>



      </ContentTemplate>
       </asp:UpdatePanel>
     </form>
```

Comment: Are these `tabs` added to a element inside `update panel` ?